# Sharepoint: How to add file to without changing version?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to add new version of the file to *SPFileCollection*  **without changing version** (it is a system update of the content of pdf file)

*UpdateOverwriteVersion* allows me to change metadata but is there a way to change content (bytes) of the file?

WORKAROUND:
Ok, as [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872703/sharepoint-how-to-add-file-to-without-changing-version/7873533#7873533) found out, there is no satisfactory solution to this.
I found two workarounds:

1.
(Be aware that turning off the version control could lead to wrong behavior, if there are people working on that list... – [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181108/stefan))

```
oFile = oWeb.GetFile(url);
oFile.Item.ListItems.List.EnableVersioning = false;
oFile.Item.ListItems.List.Update();
oFolder.Files.Add(oFile.Name, aBytes, fileProperties, true);
oFile.Item.ListItems.List.EnableVersioning = true;
oFile.Item.ListItems.List.Update();
```

2.

```
oFile = oWeb.GetFile(sAdres);
int iFileVersion = oFile.UIVersion;
oFolder.Files.Add(oFile.Name, aBytes, fileProperties, true);
oFileVersion = oFile.Versions.GetVersionFromID(iFileVersion);
if (null != oFileVersion && !oFileVersion.IsCurrentVersion)
{
    oFileVersion.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You can load the `SPFile` object and then call [`SPFile.SaveBinary(Stream, SPFileSaveBinaryParameters)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557228.aspx) method to update it's content.</s>

With the [`CreateVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilesavebinaryparameters.createversion.aspx) property of the `SFileSaveBinaryParameters` you can specify whether a new version should be created or not.

> [...] this is by design. As far as I know , there is no other solutions on it.

A quote from a moderator at [Microsoft TechNet forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/80c41276-4c89-4412-a709-f6bbc240ece4#80c41276-4c89-4412-a709-f6bbc240ece4).

Comment: Hmm, I tried to use:
`SPFile oFile = oWeb.GetFile(url);
                
                oFile.SaveBinary(memoryStream, new SPFileSaveBinaryParameters()
                {
                    CreateVersion = false,
                    CheckRequiredFields = false
                });`
 but it adds new version anyway... am I doing something wrong? Should I do something more?

Comment: @Robert: Sorry never used that switch before. In the method `SPFile.SaveBinaryStreamInternal` the arg `CreateVersion` becomes `bForceCreateVersion`. Which has a "slightly" different meaning ;).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I found two solutions: turn off version control or delete previous version, none is nice ;)

Comment: @Robert: Be aware that turning off the version control could lead to wrong behavior, if there are people working on that list...

Comment: I know but I am using it for night batch work (ocr of pdf documents) so my process is should by the only one that access this file. Anyway I decided to just delete previous version... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `SystemUpdate(false)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481195.aspx

Comment: I believe it does same thing as *UpdateOverwriteVersion*. But after using SPFileCollection.Add new version is already there.

Is it possible to change file with SystemUpdate?